# Keyup attribute 'name' change not working

Tags: jquery, attributes, input

Hey guys, I've got what I imagine is a simple question, but for some reason, I can't get it working right.

Expected Behavior: 
I type characters into a field, and, through a function, those characters are translated into the value of the `name` HTML attribute.

Actual Behavior:
Reflected in Firebug, the value doesn't change or update.

The Code:

```
$('input').live('keyup', function() {
    var name_value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(this).attr('name', name_value);
});
```

Just a side note: I'm using `.live()` because the element can be cloned, and those clones need to also be able to take on the properties of this `.keyup` event.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry; it's essentially `this`. Edited the code.

Comment: This seems like a weird thing to want. If I speculate wildly about the X in the X-Y problem ( http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341 ), then I would guess that you are using PHP, want an arbitrary number of inputs, and want to be able to read them all on the server. Name them `foo[]` (with the `[]`) and then you can iterate over `$_POST['foo']` as an array.

Comment: That should work as is. Verified on Chrome and FF.

Comment: @Mr. Dorward: Awesome observation, and you are very correct. I know I can bring in inputs as an array through `$_POST`, but the problem lies in wanting to organize the incoming data through categories and subvalues of those categories. This is for an online store with highly variable types of products, and I wanted to create an "option type" system that didn't just allow an arbitrary number of options within a type, but also an arbitrary number of option types themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to agree with the comments that is is a particularly odd request, but that being said...what you have already works, it's the monitoring tools that aren't updating, not the DOM, it's working correctly.

The easy way to test this is to [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the `<form>` and see what you get, to debug and see it, do this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    alert($(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/pWJd4/), works in Chrome, FireFox and IE8.

Comment: If you have category 'a' that holds options 'foo1, foo2, foo3', category 'c' that holds options 'bar1, bar2, bar3' and so on, what would you recommend as the best way to bring those both through `$_POST` so that you can easily associate them on the other side?

Comment: @dclowd9901 - I'd return an input with a comma separated list of names that go with the category, just number the inputs sequentially "input1", "input2" or something, on the PHP side you can just `.split(',')` that value and get the post values for that category.  Though what you have works, just a bit odd :)

Answer (score -1):

in most cases you should put a die() function before live so it kills any previous function ...
so your code should look like

```
$('input').die().live('keyup', function() {
        var name_value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(this).attr('name', name_value);
    });
```

hopw this does the trick for you .

Comment: Killing any possible events set by others is not nice.

Comment: actually it will only kill events of input ... otherwise i would recommend using a id so it does not do it to ALL input tags.
$('#inputID')... then it will only kill any live first then create a new instance of live...